# SQL data retrieval issues

Tags: sql-server

I have two table profiles and tenancy_history both are connected through `PK_FK` relationship.

In profiles I have columns `(profile_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone,city_hometown,created_at,gender,referral_code)`
and in tenancy_history
`(profile_id ,rent)`

I have been asked
Write a query to find the rent generated from each city and also the total of all cities.

I wrote a code to calculate rent generated by each city but dont know how to get total rent in the same query when you using group by.

```
select city_hometown ,sum(rent) as rent_generated_from_each_city from
profiles as p
full join 
tenancy_histories as t
on p.profile_id = t.profile_id
group by city_hometown
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a inline query like below

```
select city_hometown 
,sum(rent) as rent_generated_from_each_city 
,(select sum(rent) from  profiles as p full join tenancy_histories as t on p.profile_id = t.profile_id) rentTotal_for_all_city
from
profiles as p
full join 
tenancy_histories as t
on p.profile_id = t.profile_id
group by city_hometown
```

Or you can use `Over()`

```
select distinct
city_hometown 
,sum(rent) over(partition by Name) as rent_generated_from_each_city 
,sum(rent) over() as rentTotal_for_all_city
from
profiles as p
full join 
tenancy_histories as t
on p.profile_id = t.profile_id
```